# Does page visibility API runs way before before anything else in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

The below code gives output as

> should have been called first >>  false
>
> hidden.. stop running expensive task

It seems first time its running in sequence for further page reload it somehow caching the eventlistener I guess.. and giving below output.

> hidden.. stop running expensive task
>
> should have been called first >>  false

```
console.warn("should have been called first >> "+ document.hidden);

/* event handlers */
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
   if (document.hidden) {
    console.log("hidden.. stop running expensive task")
   } else {
    console.log("not hidden.. page has focus, begin running task")
   }
});
```

**2 questions:**

1. So does this mean the eventlistener gets attached first before anything else.
2. Why first time `document.hidden` is false?

I am not able to find much about this behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
console.warn("should have been called first >> "+document.hidden);
/* event handlers */
 document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
       if (document.hidden) {
        console.log("hidden.. stop running expensive task")
    } else {
        console.log("not hidden.. page has focus, begin running task")
    }
  });
</script>
<body>

<p>
Just create a html page with this code.
Open browser console. You'll see the console statements in sequesnce.
Now if you reload this html page, the statements are out of sequence.
Somehow event callback is called first before console statement "should have been called first"</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Just create a html page with above snippet code.
Open browser console. You'll see the console statements in sequesnce.
Now if you reload this html page, the statements are out of sequence.
Somehow event callback is called first before console statement "should have been called first"

Comment: Can you put in some more context on where this is being executed?  Is it inside script tags on the page, is it inside a document.ready() callback, etc?

Comment: tried all,inside onload, document ready, or just in script tag, same result

Comment: I can't repeat your problem, unfortunately.  As far as I know the console statement should fire before the event listener is even attached (much less before the event fires).  Try changing .warn() to .log() just to make sure it's not something affecting things, and try different browsers. See if the behavior changes.

Comment: Nope. I copied your code, did a refresh as you asked.  Got the "should have been called first >> false" first, then the visibility changed messages as visibility changed.  Same after refresh.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: @charlietfl Google chrome browser

Comment: @Paul Actually I am using the page Visibility API to play & pause the carousel, and its somewhat working meaning if I move away from tab carousel pause & when I come back withing few seconds it starts to play. But when I move away from tab for so long time, dont how but carousel is starting in background and because of that I get so many spins when come back to the tab.. The Carousel: http://vinayakjadhav.github.io/jR3DCarousel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to really confirm this, but I strongly suspect this is caused by the interaction between the console and the page loading process. If you look closely, you will find that the navigation is executed before the new Document object is created. If you assume

- the old document exists until it is replaced
- the console is cleared when the page is navigated

then the logged message is a residue from the old document, displayed within the new console log.

Try to give `document` an arbitrary property:

```
console.log("should have been called first, extra >>", document.extra);
function toggleTask () {
   var msg;
   if (document.hidden) {
      msg = "hidden.. stop running expensive task";
   } else {
      msg = "not hidden.. page has focus, begin running task";
   }
   console.log(msg + ", extra >>", document.extra);
}
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', toggleTask);
window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
  console.log("called last, extra >>", document.extra);
});
document.extra = true;
```

The first navigation to the page logs

> should have been called first, extra >> undefined

I could not reproduce the second line you get on the first page load.

The reload action adds

> hidden.. stop running expensive task, extra >> true
>   called last, extra >> true
>   should have been called first, extra >> undefined

The first two lines are also shown for the next page if you navigate away from the page. (in Chrome also by a History:Back action, in FF only for a true fresh page load)

It becomes clear that the call to the `visibilitychange` event listener happens within the context of the old document, but that it is replaced only afterwards with a new Document object.

As a mitigation, you could remove the event listener before the page unload:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
  document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', toggleTask);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is very helpful & informative, you are not getting second line first time maybe because you are using `undefined` property in console.log function with `,`, can you plz try with `+` like `console.log(msg + ", extra >>"+ document.extra);`

Comment: You are right removing event listener before unloading, makes it behave "correctly"(per say). Thanks for the answer. Its clear for me now.